# angular2/ionic2 how to use *ngFor parameter in a function call

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'll preface this by saying that this by saying that I'm new to SO and to Angular2.

I'm trying to use my *ngFor loop as a parameter to pass with navCtrl.push() down the line. The goal would be to have something like Facebook Messenger, where you click the chat group that you want to access and a version of the page appears with content (messages) associated to chat group you clicked. Here is what I thought would work. The problem is in pushing/receiving the 'event' variable. I'm doing some text references in the ngFor loop as well, but I cut that out.

```
  <div *ngFor='let event of dataProvider.data.invitedEvents'> 
    <button (click)='this.navCtrl.push(groupVotePage, event)' ion-item>
    </button>
  </div>
```

However, when I try to access event in the groupVotePage with this.navParams.get('event') (with the navParams in the constructor), I get null. I'm wondering if there is any way to pass this, or if I am even going about it the right way. I know there's some backend stuff that I would need to confirm is correct, if you could let me know what that is, then that would be great too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that in template you don't have **this** I mean that when you write this.navCtrl angular will look for a property this inside of your component, second problem groupVotePage is not a property, so simply speaking everything you use in templates must be properties/methods inside of your component.

Create new method inside of component

```
public goToPage(event){
   this.navCtrl.push(groupVotePage,  { event: event})
}
```

Then button

```
 <button (click)='goToPage(event)' ion-item></button>
```

PS. Second parameter is an object which router will read. You need to pass key value pair for router to get access to your event

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying. Good insight, but doesn't solve my problem. Something to note is that I'm not having any trouble navigating to the page, which would lead me to think that using 'this' isn't the problem. The only problem I'm having is bringing the 'event' along as a parameter.

Comment: Now I can reach the page with a value: instead of this.navParams.get('event') returning null, it returns zero. But this is still not my object. Should I also make use of the key-value pair here? Or somehow add it to my constructor?

Comment: @OwenCummings try to console.log dataProvider.data.invitedEvents to see what is inside

Comment: I was iterating on IDs, so 0 is exactly what I wanted after all! Thanks a ton.